# javascript function execute order

Tags: function, callstack

hello just want to know at what order this code function will execute and why

```
doA( function(){

    doB();

    doC( function(){
        doD();
    } )

    doE();
} );

doF();
```

Comment: The easiest way is to put a log and check the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As it sits, that will call `doA` and pass it a function, then call `doF`.  That's it.  For the other functions, it depends on what `doA` does.  If it CALLS the function it is passed, then it will be `doA` then `doB` then `doC` then `doE`, then `doF`.  Again, whether `doD` gets executed at all depends on what `doC` does.